# Get input with bigger value from dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below HTML and I want to use jQuery to find out all the `input` elements with an `id` beginning with `a` that have a value bigger than `id` beginnging with `b`. For this example, the result below would select it will be `#a2` and `#a3`.

```
<div class="form">
    <input id="a1" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="form">
    <input id="b1" value="5" />
</div>

<div class="form">
    <input id="a2" value="3" />
</div>
<div class="form">
    <input id="b2" value="1" />
</div>

<div class="form">
    <input id="a3" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="form">
    <input id="b3" value="1" />
</div>

<div class="form">
    <input id="a4" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="form">
    <input id="b4" value="5" />
</div>

...
```

Comment: This question has (apparently) nothing to do with php or, at least, if you want to use jQuery on HTML, php has nothing to do with both of them :P

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/719yjbep/

Comment: It would be easy it you put a reference attribute into your a-fields to reference the id of the compare field. And a special class for your a-field should help you to do it by a single jquery selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` with condition that compares both values:

```
$('[id^=a]').filter(function(){
   return parseInt($(this).val(),10) > parseInt($(this).parent().next().find('input').val(),10) 
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yt0Lvxct/)**

Update: To get the id of elements that matches the condition

```
$('[id^=a]').filter(function(){
    return parseInt($(this).val(),10) > parseInt($(this).parent().next().find('input').val(),10) 
}).map(function(){
    return $(this).attr("id");
}).get().join("-")
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aephdwew/)**

Comment: no. this will return all input object that are with id="a.." have value bigger than id="b.."

Comment: Yes so true or false, modified your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yt0Lvxct/1/ nevertheless nice one.

Comment: That is wrong. filter should return boolean value only.

Comment: I need to get all the number on the end of the id, not true false,

Comment: @ĐạtLâm: for all input that are satisfying the condition??

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'attribute begins with' selector and `filter()` to achieve this:

```
var $a = $('[id^="a"]').filter(function() {
    var aVal = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    var bVal = parseInt($(this).closest('.form').next().find('input').val(), 10);
    return aVal > bVal;
});
```

The `$a` variable will now contain the `a` elements with a higher value than their immediate sibling `b`.

> How to get all the number on the end of id a="" into an array?

To do this you can use `map()`:

```
var aValues = $a.map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(aValues); // shows all the larger A values gathered.
```

Comment: Use parseInt() function example:
var aVal = parseInt($(this).val());
var bVal = parseInt($(this).closest('.form').next().find('input').val());

Comment: How to get all the number on the end of id a="" into an array?